# How we can change linux environment variable in python?

Tags: 12.04, python, environment-variables

Let's say we are on a command line and we declare an environment variable:

```
export x=100
```

When i go to python and type :

```
os.environ['x'] = '100000'
```

If I came back to command line `x` stays `100`. Is there any way to change this variable in python ?

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to change the environment variables from a child process. And there is an exactly same question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506010/how-to-use-export-with-python-on-linux).

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you really need it, you'll have to start with a shell script, call python, and have your python communicate back to the shell script (there's multiple ways to do IPC, do some research and figure out what works for you).

Answer (score 1):

There is a *workaround* to what you want to achieve. Assuming you use bash as your shell, you can write the changes to bash initialization files(I chose `~/.bashrc`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
os.system('bash -c \'echo "export a=100000" >> ~/.bashrc\'')
os.system('bash -c \'source ~/.bashrc\'')
```

You need to prepend `bash -c`, since python uses `sh` as the default shell.

---

Idea derived from [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716011/why-cant-environmental-variables-set-in-python-persist)(different from the one [falconer](https://askubuntu.com/users/221281/falconer) posted).

Comment: This append "a=100000" to ~/.bashrc file, but the "source" doesn't work. If I exit python and do: "echo $a" the variable isn't there.